# Creating link reference in comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, hyperlinks

I'm unable to create reference to some link in a comment, as it is created in some post or answer. Is there a way I can create reference to some link inside a comment ?

Comment: While adding comment there is a button named `help` just click on it. http://i.stack.imgur.com/JxWni.png

Comment: I tried to search however I couldn't find the any similar question. Thanks @hims056.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a link inside the comment like this way,

```
[name of link](url of link) for e.g. [Creating link reference in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177003/173001) will be displayed liked below,
```

[Creating link reference in comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/177003/173001)